How to show newly inserted data in python GUI using tkinter and MYSQL DB
So my data insertion is working fine and I can confirm that it was posted on the db, but the newly added data is not fetching over the GUI. I tried to printing out the whole database entry, but the newly added data is not shown in the terminal.
I tried calling the function I am using to fetch and show the data on the GUI, as well as doing some manual error check, by printing the whole database entry, but to no avail the newly added data is not showing in the print under terminal so it won't show on the GUI as well. I can confirm that the data is inserted, because if I close and open the project the newly added data will pop out.
Here is my code for data insertion:
class AddStudentModal(ModalWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, "Add Student", "300x420+600+325")
        self.db_connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            password="",
            database="class_attendance"
        )
        self.subject_options = self.get_subject_options()
        self.block_options = self.get_block_options()

    def create_content(self):
        labels = ["Student Name :", "Student ID :", "Year Level :", "Block #:", "Subject 1 :", "Subject 2 :", "Subject 3 :", "Subject 4 :", "Subject 5 :"]
        entries = []

        for i, label_text in enumerate(labels):
            label = Canvas(self.modal_window, bg="#FFFFFF", width=100, height=25)
            label.create_text(50, 12, text=label_text)
            label.grid(row=i, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="w")  

            if i < 3:
                entry = Entry(self.modal_window, bd=2)
            elif i == 3:
                option_var = StringVar(self.modal_window)  # Create a StringVar for the block dropdown
                option_var.set("Select Block")
                options = list(self.block_options.keys())
                entry = OptionMenu(self.modal_window, option_var, *options)
                entry.var = option_var  # Assign the StringVar to the OptionMenu
            else:
                option_var = StringVar(self.modal_window)  # Create a StringVar for the subject dropdown
                option_var.set("None")
                options = list(self.subject_options.keys())
                entry = OptionMenu(self.modal_window, option_var, *options, command=lambda value, entry=entry, var=option_var: self.truncate_selected_subject(entry, var, value))
                entry.var = option_var  # Assign the StringVar to the OptionMenu

            entry.grid(row=i, column=1, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="ew")  
            entries.append(entry)

        def get_student_info():
            student_info = [entry.get() for entry in entries[:3]]
            block_number = entries[3].var.get()
            subject_info = [self.subject_options[option.var.get()] for option in entries[4:] if option.var.get() != "None"]

            if not all(student_info) or not block_number or not subject_info:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please fill out all required fields.")
                return

            cursor = self.db_connection.cursor()
            insert_student_query = "INSERT INTO student (name, student_id, year_level, block_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
            cursor.execute(insert_student_query, (student_info[0], student_info[1], student_info[2], self.block_options[block_number]))
            self.db_connection.commit()

            student_id = cursor.lastrowid

            for subject_code in subject_info:
                select_subject_query = "SELECT id FROM subject WHERE subject_code = %s"
                cursor.execute(select_subject_query, (subject_code,))
                subject_id = cursor.fetchone()[0]
                insert_student_subject_query = "INSERT INTO student_subject (student_id, subject_id) VALUES (%s, %s)"
                cursor.execute(insert_student_subject_query, (student_id, subject_id))
                self.db_connection.commit()

            cursor.close()
            self.close_callback()
            messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Data saved to database successfully!")
            
            # Refresh the data after adding a new student
           

        submit_button = Button(self.modal_window, text="Submit", command=lambda:[get_student_info(),  populate_students()])
        submit_button.grid(row=len(labels), column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)



and this is how i handle the fetching 

def populate_students():
    global subject_codes, block_numbers

    # Fetch student data
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM student")
    student_data = cursor.fetchall()

    # Create a new treeview widget
    tree = ttk.Treeview(frame0, columns=('ID', 'Name', 'Year'), show='headings')
    tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew', pady=(161,0), padx=(0,510))

    # Define the column headings
    tree.heading('ID', text='ID')
    tree.heading('Name', text='Name')
    tree.heading('Year', text='Year')

    # Clear previous data in the treeview
    for row in tree.get_children():
        tree.delete(row)

    # Insert data into the treeview
    for student in student_data:
        tree.insert('', 'end', values=(student[0], student[1], student[2]))

    # Fetch subject codes and populate the list
    cursor.execute("SELECT descriptive_title FROM subject")
    subject_codes = [subject[0] for subject in cursor.fetchall()]

    # Fetch block numbers and populate the list
    cursor.execute("SELECT block_number FROM block")
    block_numbers = [block[0] for block in cursor.fetchall()]

    # Print out retrieved data for debugging
    print("Fetched student data:", student_data)
    print("Subject Codes:", subject_codes)
    print("Block Numbers:", block_numbers)

    # Refresh the frame
    frame0.update_idletasks()

